# Why is CMake using clang instead of system g++ compiler?

Tags: xcode, gcc, cmake, g++, clang

Despite setting the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` in CMake, doing `make` on the Makefiles generated by CMake invokes the `clang` linker.

I want it to use the system `g++`and `gcc` compiler. I am on OSX Sierra.

Am I missing a setting somewhere? Here is my CMake setting screenshot.

With `clang`, I can't get a C++ library compiled as it cannot find [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) which is sitting right in my `\usr\local\lib`. I thought I give it a go with system `g++` and `gcc` compilers.

[image: CMake setting]
[image: clang linker why?]

Comment: gcc is an alias for clang on OSX (please complain to Apple).

Comment: The standard way to set up CMake to use the compiler you want is: starting with an empty binary directory, set up your environment (`PATH`, `CC`, `CXX` variables etc.) to the compiler you want to use. Then run CMake in that environment. Does it work for you if you do this?

Comment: Thank you for pointing about `gcc` and aliases! Good point about emptying the binary directory. It still failed after emptying and re-compiling.. `clang` doesn't have `\usr\local\lib` in its library path and so the linker fails. I have posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997218/add-library-search-path-to-clang

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by Mark Glisse,

> gcc is an alias for clang on OSX (please complain to Apple).