# Add library search path to clang

Tags: c++, clang, macos-sierra

How can I add `/usr/local/lib` to my `clang` library search path?

This is what I see when I list my library search paths using `clang -Xlinker -v`:

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is it OK to add it as environment variable?

This should work:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

Notice, it's `LIBRARY_PATH`, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

On the other hand, if that doesn't work for you, you should compile with the flag:

```
-L/usr/local/lib
```

And that should be sufficient, too.

EDIT: Btw, I don't know why you're using back-slashes instead of slashes... that needs explanation. Use slashes *always*. Even on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about back-slashes, corrected question. I added `LIBRARY_PATH` to `~/.bash_profile` and still the `clang -Xlinker -v` does not list and cannot find. Can I add the `-L/usr/local/lib` flag in CMake?

Comment: @dr_rk Yes, you can, with `target_link_libraries(MyExec -L/usr/local/lib)`. Replace `MyExec` with the object name you want to link in your cmake file. Also, note that adding stuff to bashrc isn't always the right way to do it. Just execute that command in your shell.

Comment: Thanks! I have managed to solve the problem using your suggestion of including with `-L` flag. I added `-L/usr/local/lib` to the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable.

Comment: Any idea why LIBRARY_PATH isn't working? In my case even though I set LIBRARY_PATH the libraries which are in system directories are being used.

Answer (score 7):

With the -L flag you can add additional paths to your library path.

Answer (score -4):

its, capital I (i), not capital L.  Example:

clang -fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow,signed-integer-overflow,shift,pointer-overflow -Wall -Wno-format-extra-args -g  utilities.cpp -I/Users/myName/Git/myProj/src/libs "$@" && ./a.out

Comment: `I` is the include search path, `L` is the library search path.